# Java Serial Communication -> Problem with EventListener

Tags: java, serial-communication

i'm trying to use Java Serial Communication to read measured values from a serial device. The task is to send the **ASCII** Code for 9 (57 in decimal) to the device and it will return the current value that is measured. In first place, I want to make sure that some value is correctly send back. So far, the connection works and when i changed the `getListeningEvents()` method to check for `SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_WRITTEN` it worked and showed me my phrase "Reading possible", but in this case this only shows that data got transferred.

So the number is send correctly, but I can't get an answer and the program gets stuck after printing "Written".
In many examples i saw the method `notifyOnDataAvailable()` for the `SerialPort` class, but i can't find it in the documentation anymore and i'm not sure if i have to use any other methods to initialize the listener. So my question is, what is wrong about my program, especially my `EventListener`, that it can't receive or identify the returned value?

Here is my code:

```
public class ConnectionNew implements SerialPortDataListener {

    private  SerialPort serialPort = null;
    private java.io.OutputStream output = null;
    private InputStream input = null;
    private SerialPort [] ports = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionNew connect = new ConnectionNew();
        connect.connectPort();
        connect.initIOStream();
        connect.initListener();
        connect.writeData();

    }
    
    public void connectPort() {
        ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        System.out.println("Select a port: ");
        int i = 1;
        for (SerialPort port : ports) {
            System.out.println(i++ + ": " + port.getSystemPortName());
        }
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int chosenPort = s.nextInt();
        serialPort = ports[chosenPort - 1];
        if (serialPort.openPort()) {
            System.out.println("Port opened successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unable to open the port");
            return;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean initIOStream(){
        input = serialPort.getInputStream();
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Streams Connected");
        return true;
    }
    
    public void initListener() {
        serialPort.addDataListener(this);
        
    }
    
    public void writeData(){
        try {
            
            output.write(57);
            output.flush();
            
            System.out.println("Written");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    @Override
    public int getListeningEvents() {
        return  SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Reading possible");
        
    }

}
```

I'm very happy about any hints, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which serial port implementation are you using?

Comment: *i changed the getListeningEvents() method to check for SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_WRITTEN it worked and showed me "Reading possible".* - ok, so why you can't keep it changed so that it will work then? Or does that create problems elsewhere? if so, where?

Comment: I'm using the jSerialComm library.

Comment: @kajacx: because then i can not get any data back, it just confirms that some data has reached the device. My goal is to get the data that the device sends back.

Comment: @Sophie_R By the look of it, the data should be in the `SerialPortEvent arg0` argument, accessed like `arg0.getValue()` (or something) in the `serialEvent` method.
However, the listener is probably asynchronous, and you program can end before you recieve the data. In that case, you need to prevent the main thread from exiting (by putting a sleep method at the end of `main` for example).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the data from the event:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent e) {
    byte[] data = e.getReceivedData​();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps for the next step. My problem is that the serialEvent method is not even called. That's what i wanted to check by printing something. For some reason my Listener does not react when data is sent back.

Comment: Your program might be ending after `connect.writeData();` try adding something like `Thread.sleep(10000000L);`